# I want to run a sql update query to a database to do the following

Tags: sql

```
cCode         cName2        cFather      iLevel          cCatCode
1           Assets            NULL          1             NULL
11          Current assets     1            2             NULL
1101        Cash on Hand      11            3             12012
110101      Cash on Hand     1101           4             **NULL**
110102      NULL             1101           4             **NULL**
110103      cashier          1101           4             **NULL**
110104     Cash on Hand      1101           4             **NULL**
```

I want to update the value for `cCatCode` where `cFather = 'cCode'`.

To copy `cCatcode` `12012` to all subsidary account like 110101, 110102, 110103, 110104 to be like this

```
cCode         cName2        cFather      iLevel          cCatCode
1           Assets            NULL          1             NULL
11          Current assets     1            2             NULL
1101        Cash on Hand      11            3             12012
110101      Cash on Hand     1101           4             12012
110102      NULL             1101           4             12012
110103      cashier          1101           4             12012
110104     Cash on Hand      1101           4             12012
```

I run this but it is not working

```
update chart set cCatCode = ccatcode where cfather =  ccode
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method (that should work in all databases) is using a correlated subquery.  For your particular data, this (or something very similar) will work in most databases:

```
update chart
    set cCatCode = (select c2.cCatCode
                    from chart c2
                    where c2.cCode = chart.Father
                   )
    where cCatCode is NULL;
```

Comment: The tricky part is that you need to make sure you update the levels in order - if you update 4 before 3, the 4 will have NULL, while 3 will have the correct value. Assuming that is what the OP wants, it's not entirely clear from the question...

Comment: @RagingBull . . . It will replace them with `NULL` values.  And Lamak . . . that is not the question being asked, at least based on the sample data.

Comment: @RagingBull . . . I am missing your point.  This would "reset" the values in the first two rows from `NULL` to `NULL`, so there would be no change.  Of course, the query could have `where level = 4` so only that one row gets updated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I tried you query. In SQL Server: `Incorrect syntax near 'c'`. MySQL: `You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: thanks a lot it works with me like a piece of cake :)

Answer (score 1):

1. For **SQL Server:**

   ```
   update c1
   set c1.cCatCode=c2.cCatCode
   from chart c1 join
        chart c2 on c1.cFather LIKE CAST(c2.cfather as varchar(max))+'%' and c1.cCode<>c2.cCode
   where c1.cCatCode IS NULL and c2.cCatCode IS NOT NULL
   ```

   [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ba29/1) demo for SQL Server
2. For **MySQL:**

   ```
   update chart c1 join
        chart c2 on c1.cFather LIKE CONCAT(c2.cfather,'%') and c1.cCode<>c2.cCode
   set c1.cCatCode=c2.cCatCode
   where c1.cCatCode IS NULL and c2.cCatCode IS NOT NULL
   ```

   [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10c0c/1) demo for MySQL

Result:

```
cCode   cName2          cFather iLevel  cCatCode
------------------------------------------------
1       Assets          (null)  1       (null)
11      Current assets  1       2       (null)
1101    Cash on Hand    11      3       12012
110101  Cash on Hand    1101    4       12012
110102  (null)          1101    4       12012
110103  cashier         1101    4       12012
110104  Cash on Hand    1101    4       12012
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best way to do the update on same table.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

UPDATE chart SET cCatCode = (SELECT cCatCode FROM chart WHERE cFather =  cCode AND cCatCode IS NOT NULL) WHERE cCatCode IS NULL;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```